# Understanding %>% operator

Tags: r, dplyr

Sorry for a noob question, but I'm new to R and I need help explaining this.

I see instruction that: `x %>%  f(y) -> f(x , y)`

This "Then" Symbol `%>%`, I don't get it. Can someone give me a dummy guide for this? I'm having a really hard time understanding this. I do understand it's something like this: 
`x <- 3, y <- 3x` (Or I could be wrong here too). Can anyone help me out here and explain it to me in a really-really simple way? Thanks in advance!

P.S. Here was the example used, and I've no idea what it is

```
library(dplyr)
hourly_delay <- flights %>%

filter(!is.na(dep_delay)) %>% 

group_by(date, hour) %>%   

summarise(delay = mean(dep_delay), n = n()) %>%  

filter(n > 10)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would you rather write:

```
library(magrittr)
sum(multiply_by(add(1:10, 10), 2))
```

or

```
1:10 %>% add(10) %>% multiply_by(2) %>% sum()
```

?

The intent is made a lot more clear in the second example, and it's fundamentally the same. It's usually easiest to think of the first expression (`1:10`) defining some data object you're working on, then `%>%` applying a set of operations sequentially on that data set. Reading it out loud,

```
Take the data 1:10, then add 10, then multiply by 2, then sum
```

the way we describe the operation in English is almost identical to how we write it with the pipe operator, which is what makes it such a nice tool.

With your example:

```
library(dplyr)
flights %>%
    filter(!is.na(dep_delay)) %>%
    group_by(date, hour) %>%
    summarise(delay = mean(dep_delay), n = n()) %>%
    filter(n > 10)
```

we are saying

```
Take the data set flights, then
    Filter it so we only keep rows where `dep_delay` is not NA, then
    Group the data frame by the `date`, `hour` columns, then
    Summarize the data set (across grouping variables), with `delay`
      as the mean of `dep_delay`, and `n` as the number of elements
      in that 'group' (`n()`), then
    Filter it so we only keep rows where there were more than 10 
      elements per group.
```

Comment: With the sum(multiply_by(add(1:!0, 10), 2)), when I enter it it shows Error: could not find function "multiply_by". And the 2nd line shows Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "add". That aside, thanks for your answer! Just wondering, so the Sequence matters here, right?

Comment: Sorry, you need `library(magrittr)` first to get those aliases (plus the pipe operator `%>%`)

Comment: I guess you both should mention `dplyr` here too

Comment: Oh okay! I'm trying to learn dplyr, and didn't realize you need magrittr. Will get it right now :)

Comment: `dplyr` imports (and re-exports) `%>%` so you don't need it per-se to use `dplyr`, but `magrittr` comes with its own set of utility functions (that you don't get by default when just loading `dplyr`)

Comment: ^thanks! I'll youtube magrittr now :)

Comment: @user3784616, just read [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/magrittr.pdf)

Comment: ^thank you very much! +10 kudos points to you all :)

Comment: magrittr has a youtube channel?